# change background color with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Continue discovering angularjs and stucked at changing colors on object, if it true - for ex. green, if false another color. I've tried to realized it but it shows me to all rendered data one color:

```
rssFeedService.getFeed().then(function (results) {
    $scope.feed = results.data;

    $scope.feed.forEach(function (checkitem){
        if (!checkitem.isRead) {
            $scope.read = {
                "color": "white",
                "background-color": "coral"
            }
        } else {
            $scope.read = {
                "color": "white",
                "background-color": "green"
            }
        }
    });

}, function (error) {
    //alert(error.data.message);
});
```

Here i'm getting data and with loop i'm set the color.

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="q in feed">

    <a href="{{q.link}}">
        <h1 ng-click="isReadClick(q.id)" ng-style="read"> {{q.title}}</h1>
    </a>

    <h4>{{q.body}}</h4>

</div>
```

I Suppose that this happens because I'm using ng-style and should use ng-class for set static color.

Comment: Try console.logging the `read` object in the javascript, and try to print it in the html (`<pre ng-bind="read | json"></pre>`). Do they match?

Comment: what is `rssFeedService`? Is this an angular service or a third party library's function ?

Comment: @S4beR, It's http.get function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ng-repeat then I would recommend ng-class.

```
<h1 ng-click="isReadClick(q.id)" ng-class="q.isRead ? 'green' : 'red'"> {{q.title}}</h1>
```

In the example, if `q.isRead` value is a true then set class `green` else set class `red`.

Comment: q.isRead determine true or false, I've tried your example, but it didn't set color on it

Comment: @Vitaliy you set a class on your element.

Comment: if I understood you correctly, I set this class on q.link or q.body and it did not change colors

Comment: Going by your example, you should be able to replace your h1 tag with my one. You should create the classes .green and .red as well.